# Language likebox Facebook - English to French

Tags: facebook

I'm from France and I use BoxFacebook on my site.

I changed the language to French in the code:

```
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/fr_FR/all.js#xfbml=1";
```

But the text always appears in English. How can I make it display in French?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that if you are already connected to facebook, it will use your account's default language. If you change the language of your facebook profile to french, the like button will now be displayed in french.